# What would be the consequences of factoring being NP-complete?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, np-hardness, factoring

Are there any references covering this?

Answer (score 30):

As well as implying NP=co-NP, it would also imply that BQP contained NP.

It would also seem to imply that hard instances of NP-complete problems were easy to generate.

Answer (score 22):

Since integer factorization is known to be in both **NP** and **co-NP**, a proof that it is **NP**-complete would imply **NP** = **co-NP**, which is considered highly unlikely.

There is an interesting discussion at this [old post by Lance Fortnow](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2002/09/complexity-class-of-week-factoring.html).