# P with integer factorization oracle

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, oracles, factoring

I just read the "[Is integer factorization an NP-complete problem?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/159/1800)" question ... so I decided to spend some of my reputation :-) asking another question $Q$ having $P(\text{Q is trivial}) \approx 1$:

> If $A$ is an oracle that solves integer factorization, what is the power of $P^A$?

I think it makes RSA-based public-key cryptography insecure ... but apart from this, are there other remarkable results?

Comment: @Vor that part `P(Q is trivial)=1` is a joke, isn't it?

Comment: This question suggests a related and (perhaps) more natural question: if _R_ is an oracle that returns _f_(_M_,_n_) as the maximal runtime of a polynomial-time Turing machine _M_ over all inputs of length _n_, what is the power of P^R?

Comment: @Vor: Isn't this the same as asking "Which problems can be polynomial-time Turing reduces to integer factorization?" Or did you intend to ask something else?

Comment: I'm a newbie, so my question is almost a curiosity. All started from a simple thought: out "in the real world" I see many NP-complete problems (a postman trying to reserve his strength, a family that is moving and want to fit its furniture in a truck, ... :-))). But I don't see "factoring problems" ... although they MAY be simpler (between P and NPC). ... perhaps reality hates multiplications :-D :-D

Comment: a related question is [What are the consequences of factoring being NP-complete?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/167/186), also see Lance Fortnow's [Blog post](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2002/09/complexity-class-of-week-factoring.html)

Comment: See also [Consequences of Factoring being in P?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5096/consequences-of-factoring-being-in-p)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't have an answer to you question, but I know that a similar notion has very recently been studied, under the name of "angel-based security."

The first paper studying this concept is [Prabhakaran & Sahai (STOC '04)](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1007394). In particular, they wrote in the abstract:

> [... we give the] adversary access to some super-polynomial computational power.

Another important paper which discusses this notion is that of [Canetti, Lin, & Pass (FOCS 2010)](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/FOCS.2010.86). I watched some parts of their conference presentation (on [techtalks](http://techtalks.tv/focs/2010)), and if I recall correctly, they start with an example similar to what you mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 13):

Obviously any decision problem that can be reduced to factoring can be solved with a factoring oracle. But since we're given the ability to make multiple queries, I tried to think of a non-trivial problem for which one would want to make multiple queries.

The problem of computing the Euler totient function seems like such a problem.  I don't know  how to solve the decision version of this problem by a Karp-reduction to the decision version of factoring.  But with Turing reductions, it's easy to reduce this to factoring.

Comment: Here's a [related post in MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3274/how-hard-is-it-to-compute-the-euler-totient-function) concerning the complexity of computing totient function.

Comment: Small addition: there are also polynomial time reductions in the other direction, computing Euler's Totient function -> Factoring. I have not checked whether the known reductions work for the decision version of these problems though. Still, being able to compute the Totient function (or even a fixed multiple of it) gives you the ability to factorize. [Shoup's book](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1529931) dedicates a chapter to this.

Answer (score 10):

Elaborating on Joe's earlier answer: note that $\textrm{FACTORING} \in \mathsf{NP \cap coNP}$. The latter is the [second lowest class in the "low" hierarchy](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo%3aL#lkp): which is to say that $\mathsf{NP^{NP \cap coNP} = NP}$. This implies in particular that $$\mathsf{P^{\textrm{FACTORING}} \subseteq NP^{\textrm{FACTORING}}} \subseteq \mathsf{NP}.$$
We may make similar remarks for $\mathsf{coNP}$ and $\mathsf{BQP}$, to show that at least on a coarse-grained level, $\mathsf P^{\textrm{FACTORING}}$ has the same complexity bounds as the problem $\textrm{FACTORING}$ itself, which is to say
$$ \mathsf{P^{\textrm{FACTORING}} \subseteq NP \cap coNP \cap BQP}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the new answer. BTW, are you aware of papers/results about reducibility among problems in $NP \cap coNP$?

Comment: It's even in $\mathsf{UP} \cap \mathsf{coUP}$ (the same reasoning as in your answer holds).

Answer (score 6):

Since factorization is in NP, you can at least say that $P^A\subseteq \Delta_2^P$.

Answer (score 5):

Well, as others noted factorization is in $\mbox{FNP}$, so we have $P \subseteq P^A \subseteq \Delta_2^p$ (i.e. $P^{NP}$). However, the decision version of factoring is also in $\mbox{BQP}$, so in fact we can do slightly better and get $P \subseteq P^A \subseteq P^{NP \cap BQP}$.